# Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when using check box cells on secondary sheets

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

Every time I get the above run time error when I double-click to check the box or when I try to edit the data within a different cell by double-clicking. When I run the debug, this is what it shows me:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim lCol As Long
lCol = 10 'number of columns to the right for link

For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
   With chk
      .LinkedCell = _
         .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, lCol).Address
   End With
Next chk
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("Check_box")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
        Target.Font.Name = "marlett"
        
    If Target.Value <> "a" Then
        Target.Value = "a"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Target.Value = "a" Then
        Target.ClearContents
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

It highlights this line:

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("Check_box")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

as if something is missing, but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Have you defined the range "Check_box" on this worksheet?  If it's a range on a different worksheet then you'd need to include a reference to that sheet

Comment: @bn_ln - you'll get a runtime error if you try to intersect ranges from different sheets.

Comment: Thanks @tim Williams - it doesn't make much sense to do so either.

Comment: No, the range should be within this worksheet only, it should function independently of other worksheets in this book